# What additional meaning does "as" impart to this phrase (see below)?

Tags: meaning

"I shall render assistance when, if, and as I can."

My question: What additional meaning does the word "as" impart to the sentence given above? It seems superfluous to me, but maybe there is a subtlety that I do not grasp.

Comment: *as I can*, in the way I am able to ( render assistance)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the following three restrictions on your ability to help.  ("Can" means able to.)

1. Time (when)  You'll help when time permits.  You may have other, higher demands on your time.
2. Possibility (if)  You'll help if physically possible.  Acts of God may intervene.
3. Extent (as)  You'll help to the extent of your ability.  Requests for help beyond your qualifications will be in vain.

In other words you'll help as time, fate, and your skills will allow.

That said, it's pretty much formulaic and may mean "I'll help when I feel like it."